# Frigidaire Freezer leaking water into bottom of Fridge

Tags: leak, refrigerator, freezer

I've had an ongoing issue with my apartment unit's Frigidaire Fridge where the Freezer has been leaking water into the fridge daily, and there's been enough to where it can pool at the bottom and possibly leak.

[image: Where the water leaks into the fridge]

I can stick my finger into the back of this part and feel ice that has formed up.

A small plastic container can hold the water that drips in, but I did recently find enough to where it was nearly full.

Here is a shot of the freezer.

[image: Freezer image]

I have attempted to use a turkey baster to squeeze hot water into the openings to try and maybe clear out some ice that has formed up, but with no results.

This hasn't become a critical issue, but it is annoying enough. What can I do to stop it and prevent from happening in the future?

Comment: Assuming you rent your apartment, likely the fridge is owned by the landlord and you will have to have them make a repair like this. You might get lucky if they decide to just replace the fridge.

Comment: I would be checking the seal on the freezer section the only reason for large amounts of water is the door is being held open for two long or the seal is damaged causing the icing of the coil then the water at the defrost cycle.

Comment: The freezer seal was something I considered might be part of the issue, but there was nothing wrong with the sealing after I had checked. That said, I am taking care to make sure the freezer is closed properly if I do open the door.

I do rent the apartment, so I will likely have to put a call in for maintenance (again). Though, given the landlord's "cheap tendencies", the odds of the entire fridge being replaced are slim.

Also, apologies for the late response. I did take the time to observe what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this hasn't been updated for over a year since the original post, since the maintenance crew came by and simply replaced the fridge. Problem solved. I had forgotten the post until I got a notification for an answer.

I'm not sure what the downvote was for. If it was due to a lack of detail, there's only so much detail that I could provide since I wasn't going to attempt a deeper self-service a fridge that doesn't belong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Before the problem started, did you usually hear a circulating fan running in the refrigerator or freezer when you opened the door? Do you not hear it any more?

If the circulating fan stops working, the evaporator coils will form a big block of ice and when the unit tries to defrost, it will leak into the refrigerator.

If this is the problem, it's a pretty quick and easy repair to replace the fan motor. It involves removing the shelves, unscrewing one or more panels in the refrigerator compartment and removing/replacing the fan motor. Best to unplug before starting.

You may have to manually defrost the ice block with a hair dryer and towels before you replace the panels.

Comment: Unfortunately, opening up the panels inside of the fridge is more suited for whatever maintenance person is able to come by. But this is something I can bring up with them once they do show up.

Comment: It could be the fan but then the temps also increase because of no circulation.